# how to convert uint64_t value in const char string?

Tags: c

See in one situation

`uint64_t trackuid = 2906622092;`

Now I want to pass this value in one function where function argument is `const char*`

```
func(const char *uid)
{
   printf("uid is %s",uid);
}
```

This should print

```
uid is 2906622092
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Any reason the function can't just take a `uint64_t`?

Comment: ...bcz that function is one API of some plugin that i cant change

Comment: @Thanatos: it's not all that unusual for one person to think of a uid as a string, while another person knows that they always use a numeric value and hence it could be represented as an integer. IIRC, Twitter has an option in its APIs to return UIDs as strings rather than numbers in its JSON responses. They're quite *big* numbers, and it wants to help out languages that don't have an integer type capable of holding a Twitter UID.

Comment: @SteveJessop i agree with you.. +1 for such nice example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
// length of 2**64 - 1, +1 for nul.
char buff[21];

// copy to buffer
sprintf(buff, "%" PRIu64, trackuid);

// call function
func(buff);
```

This requires C99, however, my memory says the MS compiler doesn't have `PRIu64`. (`PRIu64` is in `inttypes.h`.) YMMV.

Comment: It's not calculating, rather hard coding. Calculating would be `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10 + 1 + std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed + 1`, but we are in C...

Comment: @Maxim: Or in C, `(((sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT) + 2)/3)+2` gives a reasonably simple upper bound, although it isn't a tight bound. `+2)/3` is to divide by 3 rounding up, 3 is an approximation to the base-2 logarithm of 10, and +2 is one for a nul byte and one for sign, although in this case we have an unsigned type so we could leave that out.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - so this would be better in C++?

char buff[std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::digits10 + 1 + std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::is_signed + 1];

sprintf(buff, "%" PRIu64, trackuid);

Comment: @davidkomer You also need + 1 for the leading digit and +1 for the zero terminator.

Answer (score 8):

Use `snprintf` to convert numbers to strings. For integer types from `stdint.h` header use the format macros from `inttypes.h`.

```
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS // non needed in C, only in C++
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void func(const char *uid)
{
    printf("uid is %s\n",uid);
}

int main()
{
    uint64_t trackuid = 2906622092;

    char buf[256];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%"PRIu64, trackuid);

    func(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: nitpick: Shouldn't the array be initialized with 0 & `snprintf` have one less than sizeof for terminating `NUL` character? (Ofc you won't write 255 char here ... )

Comment: `sprintf` should be sufficient, if you have a sufficiently large buffer. Otherwise, another.anon.coward's comment applies. Either way, `256` is a bit overkill, no? Otherwise, +1 for being the first post to actually use the right format specifier.

Comment: Unix/Linux's `snprintf` always zero terminates. Windows' one doesn't.

Comment: @Maxim Yegorushkin: This I did not know. I thought they were all guilty of not terminating. Seems that POSIX even says they should, and Windows is the odd child out.

Comment: @Maxim: Windows doesn't have `snprintf`, although it does have an almost wholly unrelated function, `_snprintf` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
char buf[40];
memset (buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
snprintf (buf, sizeof(buf)-1, "%llu", (unsigned long long) trackuid);
func(buf);
```

should work when `sizeof(unsigned long long) == sizeof(uint64_t)`

**EDIT**

but the better answer is by Maxim Yegorushkin to use `"%"PRIu64`

Comment: But the signedness of `long long` is never that of `uint64_t`. Why not use an `unsigned long long`, if you're going to go down that road?