# uint64 to string in C

Tags: c, unsigned-integer

I have a `uint64` value that I want to convert into a string because it has to be inserted as the payload of an HTTP POST request.

I've already tried many solutions (`ltoa`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323159/how-to-convert-uint64-t-value-in-const-char-string) solution ) but my problem still remains.

My function is the following:

```
void check2(char* fingerprint, guint64 s_id) {

  //stuff
  char poststr[400] = "action=CheckFingerprint&sessionid=";

  //convert s_id to, for example, char* myChar
  strcat(poststr, myChar);
}
```

I want to convert s_id to char*. I've tried:

1)  `char ses[8]; ltoa(s_id,ses,10)`  but I have a segmentation fault;

2)   `char *buf; sprintf(buf, "%" PRIu64, s_id);`

I'm working on a APIs, so I have seen that when this `guint64` variable is printed, it has the following form:

```
JANUS_LOG(LOG_INFO, "Creating new session: %"SCNu64"\n", session_id);
```

Comment: What is the problem? Why did the solutions not work?

Comment: What do you mean by “convert”? Convert the value to an ASCII string?

Comment: What do you mean by 'convert to `char *`'?  Do you mean `char *cp = (char *)uint64_value;`, or do you want to convert the number to a string that contains the decimal (hex, octal?) digits for the value?  What's wrong with `snprintf()` and `PRIu64`?  You should show your best effort converted into an MCVE ([MCVE]).  And ask about the problems you're facing with it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i want, for example: guint64 value = "12345"; char * cp; //stuff;   printf("cp=%s,cp) ... with cp="12345".

Comment: I don't understand the double quotes in `guint64 value = "12345";` — typo, or please explain.  You can edit a comment for 5 minutes.

Comment: The `guint64` type isn't strictly standard — so it isn't officially clear what `printf()` conversion specifiers apply.  Assuming it is equivalent to `uint64_t`, you could use: `#include <inttypes.h>` / `#include <stdio.h>` / `char poststr[400]; snprintf(poststr, sizeof(poststr), "action=CheckFingerprint&sessionid=%" PRIu64, s_id);` to do the job all at once.

Comment: Your `char *buf; sprintf(buf, "%" PRIu64, s_id);` solution fails because you didn't allocate any space for `buf` to point at.  You need `char buf[20];` instead.

Comment: Using `SCNu64` in a context where you're not using `scanf()` or one of its relatives is perverse — a bug, in fact.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler , it works with  #include <inttypes.h> / #include <stdio.h> / char poststr[400]; snprintf(poststr, sizeof(poststr), "action=CheckFingerprint&sessionid=%" PRIu64, s_id);  !

Answer (score 4):

`sprintf` is the right way to go with an unsigned 64 bit format specifier.

You'll need to allocate enough space for 16 hex digits and the null byte. Here I've allocated 20 bytes to accommodate a leading `0x` as well and then I rounded it up to 20 for no good reason other than it feels better than 19.

```
char foo[20];
sprintf(foo, "0x%016" PRIx64, (uint64_t)numberToConvert);
```

will print the number in hex with leading `0x` and leading zeros padded up to 16. You do not need the cast if `numberToConvert` is already a `uint64_t`

Answer (score 1):

> i have a uint64 value that i want to convert into char* because of it have to be inserted as payload of an HTTP POST request.

What you have is a fundamental misunderstanding.

To insert a text representation of your value into a document, you need to convert it to a *sequence of characters*, which is quite a different thing from a pointer to a character (`char *`).  One of your options, which seems to be what you're really after, is to convert the value to a sequence of characters in the form of a C string -- that is, a null-terminated array of characters.  You would then have or be able to obtain a pointer to the first character in the sequence.

That explains what's wrong with this attempted solution:

> ```
> char *buf;
> sprintf(buf, "%" PRIu64, s_id);
> ```

You are trying to write the string representation of your number into the array pointed-to by `buf`, *but it doesn't point to one*.  Not having been initialized or assigned, its value is indeterminate.

Even if you your `buf` pointed to an array, it is essential that the array be long enough to accommodate all the digits of the value's decimal representation, plus a terminator.  That's probably what's wrong with your other attempt:

> ```
> char ses[8]; ltoa(s_id,ses,10)
> ```

An unsigned, 64-bit binary number may require up to 20 decimal digits, plus you need space for a terminator.  The array you're providing is not nearly large enough, unless you can be confident that the actual values you're going to write will not exceed 9,999,999 (which is well within the range of a 32-bit integer).